# Parametrizing a curve for calculating integral of a vector field over a curve $C$

Tags: vector-analysis

$\int_C z dx+xdy$ where $C= \{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2=4, 2z+x=0\}$. I know how to calculate the integral but I'm not sure how to parametrize the set $C$.

Any help would be appreciated, I was thinking of using spherical coordinates but the parametrization of spherical coordinates would not be based on a single variable $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
You know that $x=-2z$. Plug this into the equation of the sphere to get the curve of intersection.
Answer:
$x=-2z$ Then $(-2z)^2+y^2+z^2=4$ This is equal to $5z^2+y^2=4$ Leads to the parametrization of an ellipse so $z=sqrt(4/5)sin(t)$ and $y=2 cos(t)$ and $x=-2z=2sqrt(4/5)sin(t)$

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and just for confirmation I can then use polar coordinates afterwards right? Edit: Nevermind.. the dimensions would not match up if I used polar coordinates.. Hmm

Comment: After plugging in, you can get the equation of an ellipse. Then you can use the parametrization for $z$ and multiply by $-2$ to get the parametrization for $x$. What do you mean the dimensions do not match?

Comment: The vector field $F(x,y,z)=(z,x,0)$ and when we evaluate $F$ at $g(t)=(cost,sint)$ that's only in two dimensional vector for $g$ but $F$ takes in three dimensional vectors. So I thought polar coordinates would not work...

Comment: Where did you get $g(t)$ from?

Comment: When we parametrize $S$ with $g(t)$, i.e. with polar coordinates we would have to evaluate $F$ at $g(t)$ by definition of line integral, i.e. $\int_a^b F(g(t)) \cdot g'(t)dt$ and I think the coefficients of $cos(t), sin(t)$ should have different numbers. But because $g(t)$ only outputs a vector with 2 components but $F$ takes 3. So that's why I believed that polar coordinates would not work in this case.. I'm not sure if this will answer your question..

Comment: I wrote the complete solution in my answer, see if you understand. I think you went totally wrong with polar coordinates.

Comment: I hope the work I showed above is correct, can you kindly confirm whether if this is what you meant? Wasn't exactly sure of the range of $t$..

Comment: Your reasoning above is totally correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it phew..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91053/discussion-between-javacoder-and-bor-kari).

Comment: Isn't that what you already did though? I don't understand what more there is to do?! We have a parametrization for all $x,y,z$ Noo?